# Change layer popup style of KML served by GeoServer WMS service?

Tags: geoserver, wms, kml, style, getfeatureinfo

I need to change the style of the popup page in the KML (network) file sent by the WMS server. I looked at the GeoServer documents for this, but I couldn't find a .ftl file on my Linux server. There are only .XML files.

How can I do this?

[image: workspace XML files]

I want to make style like this

[image: style example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the freemarker templates yourself, GeoServer uses default ones from its internal libraries if they are not found in the data directory.

See this tutorial for a guide with examples, on how to customize the popup:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/googleearth/tutorials/kmlplacemark/index.html#getutorial-kmlplacemark